# Accessing URL Helpers when Rendering Partials from Rails Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, actionview, actionviewhelper

I have to render some templates and send the HTML block to SendGrid for email substitution. So, unfortunately, I am doing some rendering in model like this:

```
    view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"].first)
    view.render(:partial => template_name)
```

Even if I added:

```
    view.extend Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    view.extend ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
    view.extend ApplicationHelper
```

The partial don't have access to URL Helpers like url_for unless I explicit define the module like in the following:

```
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_user_url(user, :host => Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host])
```

Is there a cleaner way to use URL Helper in templates called from models?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am currently digging the same problem and nothing useful unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

In **Rails 5**, it is simple:

```rb
ApplicationController.render partial: 'my/partial'
```

It will have all your helpers loaded

more info: https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I found is to pass the `url_helpers` as part of the `locals`:

```
url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths['app/views'].first)
view.render(partial: template, locals: locals.merge(url: url))
```

and then in the view:

```
<%= url.thing_path %>
```

Also note you must to configure your `default_url_options` with:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
  config.after_initialize do
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: 'production.server.com' }
  end

# config/environments/development.rb
  config.after_initialize do
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
options = Rails.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options
view = ApplicationController.renderer.new(http_host: "#{options[:host]}:#{options[:port]}")
view.class_eval do       
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ApplicationHelper

  def protect_against_forgery?
    false
  end
end
view.render partial: "mailers/#{name.to_s}", layout:false
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi to access urls inside the views, you can do something like

```
view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"].first)
view.extend ApplicationHelper
```

and then

```
template =  view.render(file: '#_file',:locals => { #_path: #_path, ...})
```

Comment: But this is almost the same the OP put as example in the question